# Can template metaprogramming be used to encrypt compile-time constant data?

Tags: c++, encryption, template-meta-programming

Can template metaprogramming be used to encrypt compile-time constant data?

Let me explain what I mean with an example. Let's say I log information about a failing code line, like this:

```
if (index > MaxIndex) { Log(__FILE__); abort(); }
```

Could it somehow be possible (with template metaprogramming or other magic) to write `Log()` so that the compile-time constant string that replaces `__FILE__` gets encrypted so that the actual data that is used in the binary is the compile-time encrypted string? If not, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect. C99 only defines `__func__`, but GCC offers `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` as extensions, which behave the same. None of them are *macros*, but rather *identifiers*. E.g. C11, 6.4.2.2:

> The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator as if,
>   immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration
>
> ```
> static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```
>
> appeared, where *function-name* is the name of the lexically-enclosing function

Unfortunately, in C++11, `static const char []` is not a constant expression, and thus none of the above identifiers can be used as template-metaprogram arguments.

(By contrast, `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` *are* macros that are replaced with literals, so you could very well process those statically.)

---

(Simple showcase example:)

```
template <unsigned int I, unsigned int N>
constexpr char get(char const (&arr)[N]) { return arr[I]; }

template <char C> struct Foo { };

int main()
{
    Foo<get<2>(__FILE__)>              ok;
    Foo<get<2>(__FUNCTION__)>        err1;   // "error: the value of ‘__func__’ is not usable in a constant expression"
    Foo<get<2>(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)> err2;
    Foo<get<2>(__func__)>            err3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on `__FUNCTION__` - I changed it to `__FILE__` for clarity, since I don't want to derail the actual question to whether `__FUNCTION__` is literal or static or const or not, but whether *if* it is, then *can* it be encrypted or not?

Comment: @JohannGerell: Oh OK. Well, yes, since `__FILE__` is a constant expression. You can fix my `get` up to do something clever.

Answer (score 1):

With C++11 it should be possible with simple [`constexpr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#constexpr_.E2.80.93_Generalized_constant_expressions) functions which can be evaluated at compile time. That should be much more readable than some template meta-programming (however, it might silently fall back to runtime evaluation of a function - which might or might not be desirable in your case). Also take into account what @KerrerSB wrote about `__func__` not being a constant expression.